# Best HDD for NAS server?

Tags: hard-drive

Have you a recommandation of HDD (+2to) for a NAS server with a raspberry pi b+ please ?

And I would like know if it's possible automaticaly turn on/off the hdd when the raspberry don't call a movie. By example on windows, if I don't use the file inside my second hdd, the hdd don't run, but if I open a folder inside this hdd, the hdd run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Have you a recommandation of HDD (+2to) for a NAS server with a raspberry pi b+ please ?

Anything that's a normal drive should be fine, since the USB storage protocol is standardized and individual devices should not require any special drivers (unlike, e.g., wifi adapters).

> And I would like know if it's possible automaticaly turn on/off the hdd when the raspberry don't call a movie.

See `man hdparm` (you may have to install hdparm first, on raspbian `apt-get install hdparm`).  By default power saving modes aren't enabled, but

```
hdparm -B 127 [device]
```

should do it, then e.g. `hdparm -S 241 [device]` will set it to idle after 30 minutes of inactivity.